# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel8.brand' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*)

Tags: laravel

I already migrated my db:

[image]

As you can see `brands` is added.

On my brand controller I got this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Brand;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
    public function AllBrand(){
        $brands = Brand::latest()->paginate(2);
        return view('admin.brand.index', compact('brands'));
    }

    public function StoreBrand(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'brand_name' => 'required|unique:brand|min:4',
            'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        ],
        [
            'brand_name.required' => 'Please input brand name',
            'brand_image.min' => 'Brand longer than 4 Characters'
        ]);

        $brand_image = $request->file('brand_image');
        $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid());
        $img_ext = strtolower($brand_image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $img_name = $name_gen.'.'.$img_ext;
        $upload_location = 'images/brand/';
        $publish_image =  $upload_location.$img_name;
        $brand_image->move($upload_location,$img_name);

        Brand::insert([
            'brand_name' => $request->brand_name,
            'brand_image' => $publish_image,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

        return Redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Brand added successfully!');
    }
}
```

And then inside my `views/admin/brand/index.blade.php`:

```
  <form action="{{ route('store.brand') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
  <input type="text" name="brand_name" placeholder="Brand name"/>
  @error('brand_name')
  <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"> {{ $message }}</span>
  @enderror

  <h3>Brand Image</h3>

  <input type="file" name="brand_image"/>
  @error('brand_image')
  <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"> {{ $message }}</span>
  @enderror
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
  <button type="submit">Add Brand</button>
  </form>
```

But then when I tried adding a brand, it shows me this error: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel8.brand' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from` brand`where`brand_name `= Practice_Bom)`

Not sure what's causing this but I am pretty sure that I already migrated it as seen on the image below.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: The table in the database is plural (`brands`) but your code is using the singular (`brand`). Have you specified the table name somewhere in your code and missed the `s`?

Comment: I suggest you to delete the  `brands` table and also delete the migration from `migrations` table, And run the `php artisan migrate` command.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you set the table name in your model, set it to the plural:

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'brands';
    ...
}
```

Comment: I agree Thai, do check in your Model file. the $table variable should be set to "brands" for it to work.